# Jupyter notebookで、import tensorflow でImportError: No moduleになる。

Tags: python, anaconda

python初心者です。

インタフェース2017/3月号で60page記載の
Jupyter Notebookで
import tensorflow as tf
とすると、
ImportError: No module named 'tensorflow'
のエラーで実行できませんでした。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

tensorflow / ipythonはconda install済みです。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

試しに、tensor.pyのある、フォルダパスを下記で追加して試しましたが、相変わらず問題は解決しませんでした。
sys.path.append("c:\tmp\AI\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sympy\tensor")

何が問題か教えて下さい。

環境：Windows10 64bit
Anaconda 4.3.1ダウンロード

Comment: インターフェース 3月号の58pageパターン3で、Anacondaのインストールして、TensorFlow用の環境を作成して、そこで、conda install -cconda-foge tensorflow/conda install ipythonを実行して、jupyter notebookを立ち上げていたので、ImportError: No module named 'tensorflow'のエラーになっていたようです。TensorFlow用の環境でないところに、tensorflow/ipythonをインストールしたらエラーは出なくなりました。ただ、TensorFlowの環境でどうやってjupyter notebookで動作させるのが正しいのかご存知の方はいらっしゃいますか？

Comment: ちなみに、上記のTensorFlow用の環境作成とは、下記のことです。"conda create -n tensorflow python=3.5"  　　　　　　activate tensorflowで、tensorflow/ipythonをinstallして、jupyter notebookを起動していれば問題ないと考えていたのですが。。。

Answer (score 2):

env tensorflow に jupyter をインストールしていないので、jupyterコマンドが env tensorflow にないのでしょう。
Anacondaのデフォルト環境の方のjupyterコマンドが実行されているのではないかと思います。

activate tensorflow
conda install jupy