# ラズパイ上Jupyter notebookと他のライブラリについて

Tags: raspberry-pi, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

ラズパイで、OpenCVやtensorflowなどをインストールして、ターミナルで実行していたものを、Jupyter notebookで実行した際にうまくいきませんでした。

このようなエラーが出ます。
No module named '○○○'

ラズパイ自体にはインストールしていますが、Jupyterには連動しないのですかね？
アドバイスよろしく　お願いいたします。

Comment: [類似質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/34024/9820)の回答は試されましたか？